# Aggregate or summary?

Tags: single-word-requests

As far as I know summary is an aggregate function. When I have for example 2 files with 1-1MB of sizes, how should I talk about the summary of their size: 2MB. Should I talk about `summary size` or `aggregate size` or is there a better wording?

Comment: I would say ***total size***. Or ***combined size***.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thanks, the combined size is perfect, I was looking for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use [*summary*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/summary) here because it means something else. Other than that, it's mostly down to preference.

Although *aggregate* is technically correct, I would only use it when describing the size of a new file created by merging the two original files - not the result of summing up the two original sizes. I would also prefer using a narrower term (for example, *[aggregate functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function)* include not only *sum* but also *count*, *average* and more).

I normally label the result of summing up several values as ***total***. When referring to the total in a sentence, you could also use speak of the ***combined size*** of the two files.

Answer (score -1):

> Two files, 1 MB each file.

I think that makes it simple for people to understand

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! **1 MB each file** sounds like really bad English to me, do you have any references to back your usage up?